# error in creating react project by npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, proxy, npx

At Visual studio code im getting the second part error
and first part i can't even install anything with npm at terminal.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

```
npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: 
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: 
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I tried to change the proxy and that time it gave me an error about proxy, as a default im using localhost:8080

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

I found this from github and it worked:

```
> npm config set proxy null
> npm config set https-proxy null
> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
> npm install -g react-native-cli
```